# Keeping Default Values as Hidden Fields in a Text Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parameter-passing

I'm having some trouble with passing hidden fields and am mostly getting Undefined Index errors.

What I'm trying to do is have original default text box values "that if changed and submitted," the new default value is passed back into the text box as a new value and remains after this submission.

For example, let's say the default value in each of these four text boxes is the name of the heading above it (Text Box 1, Text Box 2, etc.). What would I have to do differently if I wanted any of these default values to change to something else written? (e.g. Text Box A, Text Box B, etc.)?

The Reset button needs to be able to change any new value to the original default values. Unless I'm advised otherwise, I might plan on doing this with Javascript because I've already wanted the Reset button to also erase a div that shows the information.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function customReset(){
    var div = document.getElementById("answers");
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
</script>

<h3 style="margin-bottom:2px;">Enter Current Variables:</h3>

<form class="variables" method="post" action="calc.php">

    <h4>Text Box 1:</h4>
    <input class="box" type="text" name="text1" value="<?php print $text1;?>" required>

    <h4>Text Box 2:</h4>
    <input class="box" type="text" name="text2" value="<?php print $text2;?>" required><br>    

    <h4>Text Box 3:</h4>
    <input class="box" type="text" name="text3" value="<?php print $text3;?>" required><br>    

    <h4>Text Box 4:</h4>
    <input class="box" type="text" name="text4" value="<?php print $text4;?>" required><br>   

    <input type="hidden" name="text1_default" value="text1_default" />
    <input type="hidden" name="text4_default" value="text4_default" />
    <input type="hidden" name="text3_default" value="text3_default" />
    <input type="hidden" name="text4_default" value="text4_default" />

    <br><input type="submit" name="button" value="Calculate"><input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="customReset()">

<?php 
$array_check = array('text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4');
foreach($array_check AS $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {
        $_POST[$value] = $_POST[$value."_default"];
    }    
}
?>

</form>
```

Comment: i am not specialist in php, but what about make form as partial view and on reset button click reload that form-partialView?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have a pre-defined value for a field and you want to send the pre-defined value if user sends blank field? Is it that? But your fields already have a value like: `<?php print $text1;?>`

Answer (score 0):

your foreach is useless nothing of your hidden fields are available with $_POST , at the first run .

It will be set after submit and then in your file calc.php. 
If the calc.php is the same as shown above then the $_POST[] is set and never runs through

```
if(!isset($_POST[$value]))
```

also your array has no value

```
array('text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4');
```

array with key and value

```
array('text1' => 'val1', 'text2' => 'val2', 'text3' => 'val3', 'text4' =>'val4');
```

if you want to get what is set in a hidden field (after submit)
`<input type="hidden" name="text1_default" value="text1_default" />`

```
if ($_POST["button"] == "Calculate") {
    [...]
   $array_check('text1' => 'v1', 'text2' => 'v2', 'text3' => 'v3', 'text4' =>'v4');
    foreach($array_check AS $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$key])) {
            $_POST[$key] = $_POST[$key."_default"];
        } else { echo $_POST[$key];}    
    }
}
```

after you change now `$_POST[$key]` you can not use it for the `<form>`
You can not change anything in your form . php runs on the server.

To change the form values you have to use a client lib like javascript